# AWS amplify SPA with angular 502 ERROR The request could not be satisfied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-amplify

I am using aws amplify for dev ops in frontend.
As Route I configured one with Route53.
On my local system I can route between those Links with angular routing

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'privacy-policy', component: DataPrivacyComponent },,
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
];
```

When I change the name from https://example.de/home to https://example.de/privacy-policy (not the real names) I get this CloudFront error (same error occurs when I use every word instead of home):

502 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.

CloudFront wasn't able to resolve the origin domain name. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner. If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

Did I forget to make some configurations?